# Tkinter - Flowing to a different window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-2.6

I'm writing a small application which has a GUI and different functionalities. In the current layout I'm following, it has a "welcome" screen which:

1) Requires the user to enter some data and

2) Allows the user to launch the intended feature.

The "welcome" screen, however, has fulfilled it's purpose once the operation mode is selected and therefore I think it would be correct to destroy it. The program should then enter the "main" window of the selected functionality (which can in turn spawn Toplevel widgets, dialogs and others). After doing whatever the user wants to do, it would be a nice bonus if the program could go back to the initial "welcome" screen.

The idea I have is making the "welcome" and every "main" window a Tkinter.Tk() instance, given that there will only be one and only one of them running at any given moment. I have, however, heard that having more than one Tk() instance, even if not running simultaneously, is a bad idea with Tkinter.

My question is: is this approach correct, or should I avoid using more than one Tk() instances in my programs? If so, which would be the correct way to do it?

Please take into account that I'm a novice programmer and this is the first time I work with GUIs which are supposed to do more than just say "hello world".

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to display only one window at a time, you could define the various "screens" as `tk.Frame`s and use the `lift` method to display the right frame:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text, height, width, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, borderwidth=20, **kwargs)
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        button = tk.Button(self, text=text, font=('Comic Sans MS', 20),
                           command=lambda: self.callback())
        button.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    def onlift(self):
        root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(self.width, self.height))
        self.lift()

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        p1 = Page(self, 'This is page 1', height=200, width=300)
        p2 = Page(self, 'Next page is 2', height=400, width=300)
        p3 = Page(self, 'We love number 3', height=400, width=600)
        p1.callback = p2.onlift
        p2.callback = p3.onlift
        p3.callback = p1.onlift

        p1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        p1.onlift()

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So in your case, you could define other subclasses of `tk.Frame`, and use them in place of `Page`.